# How to call the function in ascx.cs file from another ascx.cs file?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two different ascx controls. They placed in the same folder. How can I call function in one file from another file if there are no namespaces specified?

Example of the file which contains a function I need to call.

```
    public partial class atilektcms_cmsmoduls_security_security : StoreAwareUserControl
    {
        private void LoadUserEdit()
        {
             //function's actions
        }

    }
```

It is easy to see that here is no namespace declared. Can I declare a namespace for this file? How to do this correctly?

What also I need to do to make this function callable from another ascx.cs file? First of all I need to change the "private" to "public" I think. What's else?

Comment: You would be much better served in moving this 'common' bit of logic out to a separate class that both of these controls can call.  This is difficult to do for a reason.

Comment: @Paddy, The situation is more difficult. This function works with UI controls in ascx file. I can't place it in separate class. The other ascx control is integrated in first one, but has its onw ascx.cs file.

Comment: OK, then you may want to consider raising an event from within the inner control and handling that in the parent.

Comment: Yeah, changing access modifier won't really help you since you need the object any way. One way would be to inject the parent control into the child one's constructor, but the event approach suggested by splash27 looks much nicer and cleaner for me.

Comment: @Paddy, Control itself has a button inside and Click Event Handler on it. I need to call my function inside this handler, but I can't catch up this event in the parent ascx.cs file. Is it possible?

Comment: Nope, you can't bubble it up directly, but you could raise an custom event in your control within the button click event.

Comment: @Puddy, how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what you want is a custom event on your 'child' control:

```
public event EventHandler SomethingHappened;
```

Which you are then going to raise (if handled) in your button click event within your child control:

```
protected void myButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (SomethingHappened!= null)
    {
        this.SomethingHappened(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

And you then need to handle this event within your parent control or page and react appropriately.